# How can I render a template, but not finish the request, using express hbs?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I currently use `hbs` to render responses using handlebars templates:

```
res.render('blog-article', {
    title: article.title,
    slug: article.slug,
    article: article,
    serverVars: JSON.stringify({
        mixPanelToken: mixPanelToken
    })
});
```

In some routes, I'd like to do some server-side transforms on the HTML after `hbs` has finished.

I could load in a normal 'handlebars' and do that, but **I'd like to re-use all the caching and partials from `hbs`**.

**How can I render a layout with `hbs` without finishing the request?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any templating engine in Express, you can intercept the generated output by passing a callback to `res.render()`:

```
res.render('blog-article', {
    title: article.title,
    slug: article.slug,
    article: article,
    serverVars: JSON.stringify({
        mixPanelToken: mixPanelToken
    })
}, function(err, output) {
  ...
});
```

See [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render);

Comment: What a perfect answer: short, official docs link, and demo code. Thank you!